# __init__() takes 6 positional arguments but 7 were given

Tags: python, исключения

Хотя аргументов равное кол-во

```
 f = Func(peer_id, token, texts, text_rm, reply_photo, reply_fullname)
```

---

```
   def __init__(self, peer_id, token, mess, reply_mess, reply_photo, reply_fullname)
```

Comment: Можно больше кода?

Comment: Весь дать не могу. Но, наверное стоило указать, что ошибка появилась при передаче последнего аргумента(До этого все 6 передавались нормально)
Его я получаю таким образом.
-
reply_fullname = str(repl['first_name']) + " " + str(repl['last_name'])

Comment: Нет, нужно больше, [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш пример работает, как и ожидается:

```
class Func:
    def __init__(self, peer_id, token, mess, reply_mess, reply_photo, reply_fullname):
        print(peer_id, token, mess, reply_mess, reply_photo, reply_fullname)

f = Func('peer_id', 'token', 'texts', 'text_rm', 'reply_photo', 'reply_fullname')
```

Результат:

```
peer_id token texts text_rm reply_photo reply_fullname
```

[Напишите пример, который воспроизводит ошибку.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

- Перед `__init__` нет декоратора?
- `Func` не использует метакласс? Не наследуется от API модуля?
- Переменная с именем `Func` перед `f = Func(...)` не используется? Нет глобальной переменной с таким именем? Может вызывается другой объект?

Comment: Ошибку я исправил. По всей видимости, что то связанное с API.